# Dynamically loading views / controllers in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

We are developing an configuration tool using Angular.JS. The GUI contains 2 sections - a left panel which contains a tree view, which list all the configuration items and a right panel which  contains screens using which configuration items can be edited . There are about 6 or 7 different types of configuration items and each of them contains different views...

Currently we have a single view and controller because a single API call fetches all the data. Each configuration screen is a div tag which is  shown / hidden  where the tree node is clicked... The code is becoming more cluttered... Is there any way to separate each configuration screen as a separate view / controller and dynamically with out using routing

Comment: Why would you not want to use routing? The state managment offered by UI-Router sounds like exactly what you need?

Comment: Currently the app is in prototype,  data is all read in a single REST API call at the beginning , there is no calls to retrieve data of a single node item... So each time if we use routing, we might need to get the whole data thats the option , one thought process was to get the data at the beginning and store it in a angular service and for each screen instead of getting the whole data  from server we can use this service. not sure if this is a great idea. i will check state managment by UI Router

Answer (score 0):

What about ng-include?

```
<div ng-include="view1.html" ng-if="selected == 1">
<div ng-include="view2.html" ng-if="selected == 2">
<div ng-include="view3.html" ng-if="selected == 3">
```

And in each html u can specify own controller etc.